# Indexing the last dimension of a 3D array with a 2D integer array

Tags: numpy, indexing, mask

I have one 3D `data = NxMxD` numpy array, and another 2D `idx = NxM` integer array which values are in the range of `[0, D-1]`. I want to perform basic updates to each `data = NxM` entry at the depth given by the `idx` array at that position.

For example, for `N = M = D = 2`:

```
data = np.zeros((2,2,2))
idx = np.array([[0,0],[1, 1]], int)
```

And I want to perform a simple operation like:

```
data[..., idx] += 1
```

My expected output would be:

```
>>> data
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.]]])
```

`idx` indicates for each 2D coordinate which `D` should be updated. The above operation doesn't work.

I've found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098417/numpy-get-2d-array-where-last-dimension-is-indexed-according-to-a-2d-array) in SO which solves the indexing problem by using:

```
data[np.arange(N)[:, None], np.arange(M)[None, :], idx] += 1
```

It works fine, but looks pretty horrible needing to manually index the whole matrices for what it seems a pretty simple operation (using one matrix as a index mask for the last channel).

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

With `numpy.ix_` it does not look so horrible but the underlying idea using fancy indexing is still the same

```
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.arange(M)

xx,yy = np.ix_(x,y)

data[xx,yy,idx] += 1
```

**Note**

The problem is that you want to *change* the values of `data`. If you just wanted to have the values according to `idx` you could do

```
out = np.choose(idx,data.transform(2,0,1))
```

However, this gives you a *copy* of the values of `data` and not a *view*  which means that

```
out += 1
```

has no effect on your values in `data`.